# What is the easiest workflow to publish ePub files from highly structured database content?

Tags: epub, creation, conversion

I have a large amount of highly structured data (Bible verse translations and commentary) in an SQL database that I would like to make available in as widely usable an ebook format (or formats) as possible. The formatting is going to require a little bit more that a flat text rendering to include section headings, verse numbering, clear delineation between types of content (translated text of Scripture formatted differently than commentary), linked cross references, and a Table of Contents.

I presume that I should be generating an in-between format of some sort such as an XML file based on my data set that can then be transformed using XSLT or a similar system to a finished ebook format, but I don't know what this should be. I don't want to re-invent the wheel any more than necessary.

- Is this generally the right workflow or am I missing the boat somewhere?
- What should the in-between format be? Are there standards for this that will make the secondary transformation easier than others?

I suppose I should note that this is not a one time project that I can hack together using some GUI tools or web services — *the whole process must be scriptable from start to finish*. I intend to make the ebook generation an option from an extant site as an export option with customizable data ranges, translations, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done projects like this. I am assuming that you know how to select the data you need from your database. I would suggest you develop a template based on pandoc's extended markdown (to get the cross-referencing), merge the data with the template and then script pandoc to convert that to EPUB2 and PDF. If you want to offer a Kindle-compatible ebook (and you are giving it away), you could then script Kindlegen (available from Amazon) to turn the EPUB2 into a MOBI file.

This isn't a trivial undertaking, but it should be doable.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you generate some mark up format supported as input for [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) (i.e. markdown, reST, HTML) and generate the EPUB from that.

You should have no trouble scripting `pandoc`, but you would need some work automating the generation of the markup from your database (but not more than you would have generating XML).

Comment: If post-processing is needed, I can recommend the free software [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/).